# Fail over subscribe with SipSorcery

Tags: c#, sip

How is it possible to create a new subscription using SipSorcery, if your TCP connection died within the expiry timer of your initial subscription?
Write now I'm having a expiry timer running, and when it elapse, I'm checking if the connection is established like this:

```
while (!tcpChannel.IsConnectionEstablished(myRemoteEndpoint))
{
    //... using same from tag, but creating new call id saved as SIPRequest _request...
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60);
    tcpChannel.Send(myRemoteEndpoint, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_request.ToString());
}
```

The idea was to wait 60 seconds, then try to send a new SUBSCRIBE to the server, check if the connection is established, if not run again after 60 senconds, until the connection is established.

But the .IsConnectionEstablished seems a little unreliable to this purpose... Its like the while loop blocking for something. I can see that my SUBSCRIBE request has been sended, but I ain't receiving any response on that request.

Any ideas are appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do the IsConnectionEstablished check. When you call tcpChannel.Send it will take care of establishing a new TCP connection to the required end point if one is not available.

As to why you are not receiving a response to your subsequent SUBSCRIBE requests if you are re-sending the same request repeatedly without updating the required headers such as CSeq, Via branchid, Call-ID & from tag then it's probably getting flagged as a duplicate request.

Also you may want to have a look SIPSorcery.SIP.App.SIPNotifierClient as it is designed to maintain a subscription with a SIP server.

Comment: The issue is, that if the connection is still down when the timer elapsed, it will try to send request, but ofcause won't get any response. After approx 60 seconds, I want to check the connection, and send a new subscribe request, since I know that the old subscribe expiry has been reached. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: The SPTCPChannel class should attempt to re-establish the connection when it's asked to send a message. You shouldn't need to do anything special when your timer is reached. Are you getting any log messages when the re-send occurs?

Comment: You see, the problem is that when my timer elapse, the timer is being stopped, a SendRequest is initiated, and when a a response is received, and its a 200 OK, then the timer will start again within the expiry time received in the 200 OK msg. So the start of a new timer, is outside the TimerElapsed event. If the connection is gone when I'm trying to initiate a SendRequest on elapse time, I won't get any response, even tho the connection is reestablished AFTER the request has been send, which means my timer won't run, and my app will "die", meaning no more SIP communication. Any way to this?

Comment: So you're saying that the SIP server processing the SUBSCRIBE requests won't respond to a request if it's not on the same TCP connection that the initial request was sent on? That's not standard behaviour. The best way I can think to work around it is to detect a response timeout (you can do that by sending the request as part of a transaction) and when one is detected generate a new SUBSCRIBE request (new Call-ID headers etc.) rather than re-subscribing.

Comment: The problem is when I'm trying to re-sub within a dialog. Lets say that the timer elapse, and my app will try to send a re-sub within the dialog. But, meanwhile, the connection to my app server has been lost for some reason. This will lead to my app sending a SendRequest (or at least it think it does), but due to no connectivity, I'll never get a response, nor will the SendRequest be sent, before I'm actively make my app sending a new one. I think I'll take your idea with a timeout timer, starting the timeout timer after SendRequest, and stop it as the first thing on ResponseReceived.